# Laravel can't create policy for user model

Tags: php, laravel

I can't create a Policy for the User model.

I created Policy like this:

```
php artisan make:policy UserPolicy --model=User
```

I got the `UserPolicy.php` with CRUD actions.

Then inside `AuthServiceProvider.php` I added:

```
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];
```

But nothing happens. As I understand, the generated Policy for User model by default returns false on every action, I even explicitly added this to `UserPolicy` class:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return false;
}
```

I still can create a user.

Later I will need to check if the user trying to edit his own post or not. Everything should be forbidden for non-admin users except editing own profile (model).

I must be missing something obvious.

**UPDATE:**

If I put:

```
$this->authorize('create', $user);
```

In `UsersController` create method, it will invoke create method Policy, so it seams that something is wrong with:

```
...
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use App\User;
...
    
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];
```

inside `AuthServiceProvider`.

Comment: Yeah, on the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization look up `Methods Without Models`. It mentions a few times that there is additional steps to take, usually when using `create`

Comment: @RomkaLTU the laravel version?

Answer (score 6):

You can write this code for User Policy

in UserPolicy.php :

```
public function update(User $user, User $model)
{
    return $user->id === $model->id;
}
```

For example by this code you can update just your own profile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this in you function in controller:

```php
$this->authorize('create', $user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put  these lines in your controller function

```
$this->authorizeForUser($currentUser,'create', User::class)
```

Comment: I have been maintaining a Laravel 5.4 code recently, and it seems that regarding policies for User model, this is the only way to make it trigger the Policy methods correctly. I believe this should be the correct answer given the initial question seems to be asking regarding this specific problem. I have experienced this same issue with methods on the UserPolicy that required the $model to be evaluated as well, like update, etc.